# How to set artifact filters in yaml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

There is one option in classic release pipeline to provide filter on artifacts, its shown in this link for e.g.
[image]
In my case if it is develop branch I want Dev stage to execute and if it is release branch it should hit QA. But how can I achieve in YAML pipelines ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to set artifact filters in yaml

According to the document [What’s new with Azure Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-with-azure-pipelines/):

> We now offer a unified YAML experience, so you can configure each of
> your pipelines to do CI, CD, or CI and CD together. Defining your
> pipelines using YAML documents allows you to check the configuration
> of your CI/CD into source control together with your application’s
> code, for easy management, versioning, and control.

YAML files have corresponding YAML files on different branches, so we can directly set different deploy stage tasks in YAML according to different branches.

Besides, if you just only create YAML pipeline for the release pipeline, the [Resources in YAML pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/announcing-general-availability-of-azure-pipelines-yaml-cd/) does not support for the artifact at this moment:

```
resources:
  builds: [ build ]
  containers: [ container ]
  pipelines: [ pipeline ]
  repositories: [ repository ]
  webhooks: [ webhook ]
  packages: [ package ]
```

So, we could not set the artifact filter for the resource pipeline.

We could use the REST API to get the build branch and update the variable in the release pipeline, then set the condtion based on the variable for different stage.

Answer (score 0):

We have resolved issue by following below

We have used this for Dev

```
  - stage: DEV
    displayName: DEV
    dependsOn: []
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development'))
```

For QA we have used this

```
  - stage: QA
    displayName: QA
    dependsOn: []
    condition: and(succeeded(), contains(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'))
```